# Unable to open tel, mailto, whatsapp links in a flutter webview?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flutter, dart

I am a web developer and beginner to flutter. I created a Flutter web view application by watching a few tutorials and its working fine for iOS and Android. But when I click on '0123456789', mailto:'abc@gmail.com', WhatsApp link (https://wa.me/9712345678), it's going page Not Found. I want to open an external application for those conditions. How to handle this task in a flutter to support in iOS and Android? I used the flutter webview plugin to launch a url like:
And may i know where to add this following code to work ?

```
              if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {
                _launchURL(request.url);
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              } else if (request.url.contains("tel:")) {
                _launchURL(request.url);
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              } else if (request.url.contains("sms:")) {
                _launchURL(request.url);
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
```

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter_offline/flutter_offline.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

_launchURL(url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
Color btnColor = Color(0xff03a9f3);
Color bgColor = Color(0xffe9f4fc);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Qavenue',
      home: OfflineBuilder(
        connectivityBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          ConnectivityResult connectivity,
          Widget child,
        ) {
          final bool connected = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
          return Container(
            child: connected
                ? MyHomePage()
                : Center(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/offline_blue.gif',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      width: 200.0,
                    ),
                  ),
            color: bgColor,
          );
        },
        child: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String url = "https://example.xyz/";

  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  StreamSubscription<WebViewStateChanged>
      _onchanged; // here we checked the url state if it loaded or start Load or abort Load

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _onchanged =
        flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged state) {
      if (mounted) {
        if (state.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
          // if the full website page loaded`
          print("loaded");
        } else if (state.type == WebViewState.abortLoad) {
          // if there is a problem with loading the url
          print("there is a problem");
        } else if (state.type == WebViewState.startLoad) {
          // if the url started loading
          print("start loading");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    flutterWebviewPlugin
        .dispose(); // disposing the webview widget to avoid any leaks
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            flutterWebviewPlugin.canGoBack().then((value) {
              if (value) {
                flutterWebviewPlugin.goBack();
              } else {
                exit(0);
              }
            });
          },
          child: WebviewScaffold(
            url: url,
            withJavascript: true,
            withZoom: false,
            hidden: true,
            geolocationEnabled: true,
            initialChild: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Center(
                child: Image.asset('assets/icon/images/logo1.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to import url_launcher_string.dart too. You will need it when you specify the links.

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';
```

Run flutter pub get and then inside your main app dart (e.g main.dart) you tell it how to handle the urls.

```
      launchURL(url) async {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

The above part of code could be anywhere. You could also put it inside another dart and import it. It'd be better of course if you put it inside your webview widget class and not just anywhere like you did, unless you need to use it somewhere else too.
Afterwards you specify inside the webview widget class how to handle the urls.
e.g inside the:

```
class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
}
```

The 'NavigationDecision' part of code.
e.g:

```
  NavigationDecision _interceptNavigation(NavigationRequest request) {
    if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {
      launchUrlString('mailto:specify email address here');
      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    } else if (request.url.contains("tel:")) {
      launchUrlString('tel:specify telephone number here');
      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    }
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  }
```

In the above part of code you define the "request" and then you tell it what to do with each request. So if you define 'NavigationRequest request' then you tell it what to do with each request. If you define 'NavigationRequest name' then you specify what to do with that name. e.g.

```
  NavigationDecision _interceptNavigation(NavigationRequest name) {
    if (name.url.contains("mailto:")) {
      launchUrlString('mailto:specify email address here');
      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    } else if (name.url.contains("tel:")) {
      launchUrlString('tel:specify telephone number here');
      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    }
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  }
```

You can add more urls of course by editing the name.url.contains line and adding more else if decisions. e.g. whatsapp, telegram, viber, and so on. Just like you did with the sms.

Do not forget to call for your navigation decision code when you need it.
Inside your override where you tell your webview what's the initial url, you call your navigation decision with the name you set to it. e.g:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https:url', // Webview initial url here
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted, // Enable use of javascript
            navigationDelegate: _interceptNavigation, // Call for your navigation decision
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

We named it '_interceptNavigation' so that's what we call for. And that's as far as understanding that part of code. I hope that helped you. I explained it step by step for beginners too.